# ListVectorPlot3D

Tags: list-manipulation

I try to plot a 3D Vector plot. All Vectors start at (0,0,0) and point in directions given in spherical coordinates:

```
While[n < 100,x = RandomReal[]; 
AppendTo[rs, x]; AppendTo[Thetas, ArcCos[x]]; AppendTo[Psis, 2*Pi*x]; n++]
```

How do I convert the coordinates (`Thetas`, `Psis`, `rs`) into a List compatible with `ListVectorPlot3D`?

Best and thanks for your help!

---

## Edit

Thanks for your help.
Putting the array into the right shape is exactly my problem. Could you show me how this has to be done?

I used:

```
n = 0;
Origin = {};
Spherical = {};

While[n < 3, x = RandomReal[]; 
AppendTo[Origin, {0, 0, 0}]; 
AppendTo[Spherical, {x,ArcCos[x], 2*Pi*x}];
n++]

SphericalT = CoordinateTransform["Spherical" -> "Cartesian", Spherical]

cords = Transpose[{Origin, SphericalT}]
```

but it doesn't work to plot cords by

```
ListVectorPlot3D[cords]
```

the output looks like

```
ListVectorPlot3D[{{{0, 0, 0}, {0.0435796, 0.204158, 1.31166}}, {{0, 0,
 0}, {0.0774815, 0.267354, 1.74896}}, {{0, 0, 0}, {0.466032, 
0.498845, 4.28931}}}]
```

which in my eyes fits

```
ListVectorPlot3D[{{{x1, y1, z1}, {vx1, vy1, vz1}}, ...}]
```

proposed in: http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ListVectorPlot3D.html

Comment: Your code cannot be copy and pasted if someone wants to try your example. Can you fix that?

Comment: hi @Domi, please don't use answers to post clarifications to questions. I've moved your update into the question.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, `ListVectorPlot3D` cannot be used in this case, because this function tries to plot a vector field. Unfortunately, you don't have a well behaving vector field, since all vectors come from the origin. I suggest you create a `Graphics3D` on your own using `Arrow`. First, let's look at your data:

What you should try is `CoordinateTransform`. Here is an example how you can transform a list of Cartesian coordinates into spherical coordinates and back. You should note that `CoordinateTransform` is a function introduced in version 9.

```
cartPoints = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {10, 3}]
CoordinateTransform["Cartesian" -> "Spherical", cartPoints]
CoordinateTransform["Spherical" -> "Cartesian", %]
```

Side note: if you have your data in the form `{{r1,r2,..},{psi1,psi1,..},{theta1,theta2,..}}` you need to apply `Transpose` to get a list of vectors `{{r1,psi1,theta1},...}`. Furthermore, your way of constructing an array is not recommended. Please use `Table` instead of appending to a list over and over again. An easy way to rewrite your loop could be

```
Table[With[{x = RandomReal[]}, {x, ArcCos[x], x*2 Pi}],{10}]
```

Additionally, the *spherical points* you create seem to have incorrect intervals because `CoordinateTransform` complains

> CoordinateTransform::bdpt: Evaluation point {0.633415,0.884837,3.97987} is incompatible with the coordinate assumptions of the specified coordinate chart.

Anyway, let me give you a complete working example:

```
cartPoints = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {50, 3}];
spherical = CoordinateTransform["Cartesian" -> "Spherical", cartPoints];
Graphics3D[
 Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, #}] & /@ 
  CoordinateTransform["Spherical" -> "Cartesian", spherical]]
```

(I used a bit color for the graphic to make it more pleasing)

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you should note that this is a v9 feature and provide (simple) solutions for users of earlier functions.